# Can you break out of jail and not get attacked?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I go to jail and manage to get my stuff and break out without the guards seeing me, will the guards outside of the jail attempt to attack/arrest me again, or will they just leave alone for a while and say that famous, "Wait, I know you!" (xd)

Comment: I am not too sure about being attacked as I am more of the stealthy type than mass murdering sorts when doing crimes but they will definitely attempt to arrest since the bounty is not cleared. Usually at the instance when I first escape from a jail they will only arrest if they see me or I talk to them.

Answer (score 12):

If you escape from jail, your bounty will remain, plus you risk an additional 100 gold bounty if you're caught while trying to get out.

Answer (score 3):

When you perform a jailbreak a bounty of 100 gold is *added* to your current bounty - this happens regardless of getting caught. After completing the jailbreak guards will *not* interrogate or attack you, only saying "Wait, I know you!".

There was conflicting information about this online so I tested it without Mods on a fresh character. I stole a knife in Riverwood (9 gold bounty), ran to Whiterun and talked to a guard, got sent to prison, escaped, grabbed items on way out, ran around town jumping in front of guards with 109 gold bounty.

To remove the bounty you'll need to pay it. Or,

> If you are part of the thieves guild and have enough reputation in the specific hold there will be a bribe a guard option to pay the bounty at a discount. If you use this bounty payment option you can immediately steal back the bounty from the guard (so I've read online).

There's also [wikia guide](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Jail_Break_(Skyrim)) on how to escape each of the jails.